# OpenERP, adding new column in rml report using python

Tags: python, report, odoo, rml

Here is the snip code I took from survey statistics report python object

```
if percantage:
    rml += """<td color="#FFF435"><para style="answer_bold">""" +                   
        tools.ustr(percantage) +"% (" + tools.ustr(cal_count) + """)</para></td>"""
rml += """<td color="#FFF435"><para style="answer_bold">"""+ tools.ustr(summery_perc)     
    +"%(" + tools.ustr(cal_count) + """)</para></td>"""
```

what I want to do is in matrix_of_choices_only_one_ans question type I want to add average of answered question per each column and overall summary I already did the calculation code part  but when I add the new column (seen line it 3) it popups error. What am i missing here? your any help would be appreciated I am new to rml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It popups error because you have a blockTable with a defined number of columns (in colWidths) so we can't have more columns than this defined number.

Comment: #Quentin THEURET thanks I thought clowidth is for width, I need to read about rml

Comment: Here is the link to the documentation of RML : www.reportlab.com/docs/rml2pdf-userguide.pdf − Some topics are not integrated into the OpenERP/Odoo RML parser.